# Static nested class does not initialize outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes

When i initialize the static inner class i am expecting that outer class is also initialized and will print   `I should see this as well.` however this is not happening and i am getting only `class Main` as a output

```
 class AA {
    static {
        System.out.println("I should see this as well.");
    }

    public static class BB {
        BB() {
            Object o = Main.class; 
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    };
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AA.BB();
    }
}
```

Can some one help me , explaining this behavior.

Comment: Static inner classes are not as closely related to their outer classes as non-static ones. In fact you can see the outer class of static inner classes as some kind of namespace (or package).

Comment: *A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.*  [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Once they're compiled, they're sufficiently separated that you can load one class without the other.

Comment: One of those questions that make your head spin for a second ;-) ... funny thing. Have my vote for that!

Comment: Wow - so AA and AA.BB implemented as different classes? Never thought of that!

Comment: @GhostCat explained the same but i really want to see that via some tool or some code any thing that can stamp on this

Comment: @GhostCat :) yes

Comment: @GhostCat --thanks got it... :)

Comment: So, the updates for my answer are in. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static inner class" in Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3

Comment: @LewBloch--I am not sure what are you pointing at, but what will you say when a inner class is marked as static... :(

Comment: I will say that is not an inner class, per the JLS, as I linked. Read the Fine Manual. Follow the link.

Comment: "An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static."

Answer (score 3):

Thing is: that **static** initializer block gets executed lazily. Meaning: this code gets executed the first time that the AA class is really "required". But AA is not required to instantiate AA$BB.

If you change

```
BB() {
  Object o = Main.class; 
  System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

to *really* require class AA to be loaded:

```
BB() {
  Object o = Main.class; 
  System.out.println(o.toString());
  new AA();
}
```

then that other string gets printed, too.

Keep in mind: it is only within your **source** code that BB is "inside" AA. From a class loader point of view, AA and BB are (somehow) two **independent** classes coming from **two** different class files!

Edit, given the question "how to see" that:

A) I replaced Main.class with Test.class and compiled, and I find in my file system `AA$BB.class  AA.class  Test.class` afterwards.

B) now you can run `[javap][1] -c "AA$BB.class"` to see more about the content of that class

Comment: You are right when  you say "From a class loader point of view, AA and BB are (somehow) two independent classes coming from two different class files!"--- I want to check this behavior any tool or other way you recommend to see this behavior.

Comment: @Show Stopper, ??? Your question includes code that shows this behavior already! It's the basis of your question, that it shows the behavior!

Answer (score 3):

A nested class creates a distinct class.

Here you would have two classes :

- AA.class
- AA$BB.class

Using the second one doesn't require to load the first one as the second is a public static class.

Comment: There's no inner class in the question.

Comment: `BB` is static. It therefore is not an inner class. Read the Fine Manual at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3.

Comment: "An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static."

Comment: @Lew Bloch You learn me something.  To complete : "Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.". I edit consequently.

Comment: You haven't edited your answer to remove the incorrect reference to "inner class".